# Removing Null results from AVG

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I've been doing some work regarding AVG. My previous solution didn't work. However, after some revision and help it's now returning the correct results. The results do however, keep returning NULL Values for agents as they don't have results in the CASE WHEN date range.

I've tried adding IS NOT NULL into CASE WHEN argument but it tells me the expression does not exist.

```
SELECT Employee,
       AVG(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= '2019-01-01' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-01' THEN NewScheme END),
       AVG(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= '2019-01-04' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-07' THEN NewScheme END),
FROM Salereport
WHERE Business Area = 'Sales'
GROUP BY Employee;
```

When adding is not null i'm told the expression doesn't exist.

Comment: which column are you going to use the is not null?

Comment: Use `COALESCE(AVG(...), 0)` to replace the `NULL` values with `0` (or change the `0` to whatever you want it to be in the case of a `NULL` result)

Comment: What is the expected output? What happens if an employee does not have a sale in first range but has one or more in second range?

Comment: I need to Null the employee that don't have an average for the months specified in the CASE WHEN.

Comment: AVG (1, null, 5) = 3. AVG (1, 0 , 5) = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a WHERE clause to remove employees that do not have sales in either range. It could still show NULL in one of the average columns though:

```
SELECT Employee,
       AVG(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= '2019-01-01' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-01' THEN NewScheme END),
       AVG(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= '2019-01-04' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-07' THEN NewScheme END)
FROM Salereport
WHERE Business Area = 'Sales'
AND SaleDate >= '2019-01-01' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-07'
-- if the ranges do not overlap then list them separately and combine with "OR"
GROUP BY Employee;
```

Comment: Don't know why I over complicated this in my head. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Build your query like this. Put `ELSE 0 End` and `ISNULL()` to avoid nulls your your AVG

```
SELECT Employee,
       AVG(ISNULL(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= '2019-01-01' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-01'
                THEN NewScheme ELSE 0 End, 0)
           END),
       AVG(ISNULL((CASE WHEN SaleDate >= '2019-01-04' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-07'
                THEN NewScheme ELSE 0 End, 0)
           END),
FROM Salereport
WHERE Business Area = 'Sales'
GROUP BY Employee;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT Employee,
       AVG(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= '2019-01-01' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-01'
                THEN ISNULL(NewScheme, 0) ELSE 0 End
           END),
       AVG((CASE WHEN SaleDate >= '2019-01-04' AND SaleDate < '2019-04-07'
                THEN ISNULL(NewScheme, 0) ELSE 0 End
           END),
FROM Salereport
WHERE Business Area = 'Sales'
GROUP BY Employee;
```

Comment: null's aren't included in the AVG result. 0's are.